# React native android : how to setup WebChromeClient

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am beginner in javascript
I have to use chrome web client in React Native because firebase auth is not working in Native android webview

I tried this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

but it says you cant use firebase auth in native webview 
now I am following this tutorial

https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge

it says

add the following code to add the package to MainApplication.java

```
(MainActivity.java if RN < 0.29)
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
                new WebViewBridgePackage() //<- this
        );
    }
```

I can't find any file called MainApplication.java in my react native project
I am using create-react-native-app
**Please** help me with javascript-firebase auth & javascript functionality in mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expo don’t have react-native-webview-bridge in our core API. If you need to add a package with custom native code (java or objective-c) then you would need to [detach to expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html) .

This is possible soultion for your problem , it will be better .